# Bootstrap 4 Columns, 2 Hidden

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a bootstrap page that will have a 4 column grid system. However, 2 of these will be hidden columns. One to the left and one to the right. When a user clicks a toggle button on the left, the user can see 3 columns, like wise, clicking a toggle button to the right will display the 4 columns.

How can I do this using in bootstrap grid?

Comment: What you want is to when there are only two columns visible, they will take  up the entire width? I mean when you have two columns, you have `col-lg-6` and when you have 4 columns you have `col-lg-3`?

Comment: exactly. So do I have to change these using jquery?

Comment: Yes, you need to use jQuery (you could do it with vanilla JavaScript but since bootstrap already has jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept here is that on `.click()` I do the following:

- I remove all `col-lg-*` classes based on how many `.hidden` columns exist.
- I toggle the `.hidden` class for the first or last column.
- I add the correct `col-lg-*` class depending again on how many `.hidden` columns exist.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <button class="btn btn-info toggle-item toggle-first">Toggle first column</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info toggle-item toggle-last">Toggle last column</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="first column hidden">
        first column
    </div>
    <div class="column col-lg-6">
        second column  
    </div>
    <div class="column col-lg-6">
        third column
    </div>
    <div class="last column hidden">
        fourth column
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery('.toggle-item').click(function() {
    var count = jQuery('.column.hidden').length;
    if (count === 2) {
        jQuery('.column').removeClass('col-lg-6');
    } else if (count === 1) {
        jQuery('.column').removeClass('col-lg-4');
    } else if (count === 0) {
        jQuery('.column').removeClass('col-lg-3');
    }

    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('toggle-first')) {
        jQuery('.column.first').toggleClass('hidden');
    } else {
        jQuery('.column.last').toggleClass('hidden');
    }

    count = jQuery('.column.hidden').length;
    if (count === 2) {
        jQuery('.column').addClass('col-lg-6');
    } else if (count === 1) {
        jQuery('.column').addClass('col-lg-4');
    } else if (count === 0) {
        jQuery('.column').addClass('col-lg-3');
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/ppJgfWpd08)

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on this using JQuery and Bootstrap. I added an orange border to make is more obvious (but you can remove it)

**Code**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-primary").on('click', function() {
    $(".first-col").toggle();    
    updateColumnWidth($(".col:visible").length);

  });

  $(".btn-danger").on('click', function() {
    $(".last-col").toggle();    
    updateColumnWidth($(".col:visible").length);
  });

  var updateColumnWidth = function(numOfColumns) {
    $(".col").removeClass('col-xs-3 col-xs-4 col-xs-6');

    switch (numOfColumns) {
      case 2:
        $(".col").addClass('col-xs-6');
        break;
      case 3:
        $(".col").addClass('col-xs-4');
        break;
      case 4:
        $(".col").addClass('col-xs-3');
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-6   {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row well">
  <div class="col col-xs-3 first-col">
    col 1
  </div>
  <div class="col col-xs-3">
    col 2
  </div>
  <div class="col col-xs-3">
    col 3
  </div>

  <div class="col col-xs-3 last-col">
    col 4
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Show/Hide Col 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Show/Hide Col 4</button>
```